# Login Cancelled

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK for Swift, installed via cocoapods. I've configured an example App in the following way:

1. Added a new facebook app on the developer site;
2. Added iOS application with correct bundle identifier;
3. On the iOS application edited the info.plist to add:

> ```
> <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
>   <array>
>       <dict>
>           <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
>           <array>
>               <string>fb169432773464820</string>
>           </array>
>       </dict>
>   </array>
>   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
>   <string>1</string>
>   <key>FacebookAppID</key>
>   <string>{APPID}</string>
>   <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
>   <string>AppDisplayName</string>
>   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
>   <array>
>       <string>fbapi</string>
>       <string>fbauth</string>
>       <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
>       <string>fbauth2</string>
>       <string>fbshareextension</string>
>   </array>
> ```

After this I created a custom UIButton with the following action:

```
@IBAction func facebookTouched(sender: UIButton) {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([.PublicProfile], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .Cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the UIButton the action is called and Safari browser opens the facebook page.
Since I already accepted this application I get the following message "ApplicatioName already accepted" when I press "Ok" the browsers moves to a blank page and nothing happens. If I press the "Done" button the .Cancelled case is called.

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem was on the AppDelegate were the Facebook ApplicationDelegate methods need to also be called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

        return true
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }
```